# What is the easiest way to read an RSS feed in a terminal?

Tags: xml, bash, rss, rss-reader

I'm making a script similar to [QuantumLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Link) for my own purposes and I wished to make a news app that reads the RSS feed at  `feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml`. I have scoured the internet and found a few readers written in bash but they are all either not working or not taking one url. I don't want a full program I just want to run the script and the feed with the titles and body appear. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution is a simple app. [RSSTail](http://www.vanheusden.com/rsstail/) is a very simple and little and ready-to-use program (to suck less).

But if you want more rss-feeds (to read, personal use) I think [newsbeuter](http://newsbeuter.org/) or [snownews](https://kiza.eu/software/snownews/) will be better (I'm using newsbeuter) - but they aren't usable in scripts, they are a full reader apps.

**Update**: the newsbeuter is abandon. Its successor is [newsboat](https://newsboat.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those when I've finished working out how to undo a delete I just did... *facepalm*